# Prettier date formats in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization, ruby-on-rails-4, strftime

I know I can manually make the date formats however I want with `strftime`, but are there any easy ways to quickly make dates look nicer than the `:short`, `:long`, `:long_ordinal` formats? The `:long_ordinal` looks nice but then doesn't have AM/PM, uses military time:
`September 11th, 2013 14:00` instead of `September 11th, 2013 2:00 PM`.

Ideally there's a kind of `:long_ordinal_prettier` format that has the `2:00 PM` mechanism here in America and pretty local dates elsewhere in the world.

Comment: Why is using `strftime` hard to use? Assign the format to a constant or in a YAML file and you're done.

Comment: @theTinMan - well one issue is I would like the date format pretty internationally too. Also, I'd just like to know for my Rails edification how to make `DateTime`s more readable. I'm very surprised there's not an obvious built-in Rails solution.

Comment: If there isn't, it sounds like an opportunity to help the Rails community. There are international standards (ISO) and *nix common-standards for data/time representation that Rails supports via `strftime`, which are available in every programming language via the normal `sprintf` format specifiers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a file like `config/initializers/date_formats.rb`

```
Date::DATE_FORMATS.merge!(
  long_date: '%a, %B %e, %Y %l:%M %p',
  short: '%A, %B %e, %Y',
  hyphen: "%Y-%m-%d",
  long_ordinal_prettier: "....."
)
```

You can use them like this

```
some_model.created_at.to_formatted_s(:long_ordinal_prettier)
```

Comment: How do I get the ordinal date? `%e` gives me the day of the month, but without the 'th', 'st', 'nd', etc postfixes.

Comment: Ruby doesn't support what you're looking for natively with [`strftime`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Time.html#method-i-strftime). I'll leave creating the custom format with the ordinal as an exercise, with **[a hint](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/date/conversions.rb#L11-L14)**.